# Power BI - Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, query, oracle, oracle11g, powerbi

Olá,
Estou tentando obter dados no Power BI via Query em um DB Oracle e está apresentando o seguinte erro.

**Não é possível estabelecer conexão Detalhes: "Oracle: ORA-01843: not a valid month"**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
J.JOBID,
J.JOBNAME,
--J.FOLDERPATH,
SUBSTR(R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,10, 2) "HORA START",
SUBSTR(R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,13,2) "MINUTO START",
SUBSTR(R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,10, 2) "HORA END",
SUBSTR(R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,13,2) "MINUTO END",
SUBSTR(R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,9, 6) "STARTTIME",
SUBSTR(R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,9, 6) "ENDTIME",
R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,
R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,
R.ELAPSEDRUNSECS


FROM
DSODB.JobExec J,
DSODB.JobRun R,
DSODB.JobRunLog L,
DSODB.LogTypeRef T


WHERE J.ProjectName = 'MDM_PRD'

AND J.JobName = 'Jb_PssBip_Wpd001_SelectOrigemCarregaTrilha'
AND R.JOBID = J.JOBID
AND L.RUNID = R.RUNID
AND L.LogType = T.LogTypeCode

AND r.runstarttimestamp BETWEEN '17/07/18 00:00:00,000000000' AND '17/07/18 23:59:00,000000000'

ORDER BY r.runstarttimestamp
ASC
```

Porém o campo Runstarttimestamp possui exatamente o formato que está no between. Quando eu realizo uma consulta pelo SQL Developer ele retorna os resultados normalmente.

Como é a primeira vez que uso o Power BI, existe alguma regra que não estou utilizando corretamente? Alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: Campo Starttimemstamp]

```
select sysdate from dual;
05/08/18
select localtimestamp,current_timestamp,systimestamp from dual;

05/08/18 16:34:35,657223000 05/08/18 16:34:35,657223000 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO   05/08/18 16:34:35,657209000 -03:00
```

Comment: Olá Diego. Obrigado pela resposta. Eu fiz o teste no formado indicado e retornou o mesmo erro :/

AND r.runstarttimestamp BETWEEN '2018-07-17 00:00:00' AND '2018-07-17 23:00:00'

Comment: Sem sucesso ainda. Vou é tacar fogo nessa query hahahaha

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Funcionou cara! Muito obrigado. Você é fera

Comment: Registrei o que tinha dito nos comentários como resposta para consultas posteriores da comunidade. Assim pode-se fechar essa thread

Answer (score 0):

O formato como você vê o dado ao realizar uma consulta na tabela não deixa explícito o tipo de dados que você tem na coluna correspondente. A exibição está relacionada às configurações de resultado (e suas limitações), enquanto que no banco o formato deve estar com a estrutura adequada de acordo com as diretrizes do SGBD (`timestamp` nesse caso).

> Você deve usar a função `to_timestamp` para converter a sua string no formato correto do dado quando estiver comparando com uma coluna do banco cujo tipo é `timestamp`. O mesmo vale para `date` (use o método `to_date`).

Nesse caso, sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
...
AND r.runstarttimestamp BETWEEN to_timestamp('17/07/18 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND to_timestamp('17/07/18 23:59:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

ORDER BY ...
```

Fonte: [Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855378/oracle-sql-timestamps-in-where-clause/8855484#8855484) do [SO].

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Evite utilizar conversões implícitas de texto para data/hora, pois pode se deparar com configurações diferentes entre servidores, aproveitando da conversão com **to_date**:

A formatação de conversão deve ser respeitar o texto que será convertido, como estamos no Brasil, nos acostumamos com a sequência *dia mês ano* separados por "**/**" utilizando as respectivas siglas **DD/MM/YYYY**, prefiro utilizar ano com 4 dígitos, vestígios pelo ter passado pelo alarme do bug do milênio, brincadeiras, é possível haver informações de antes de 2000 no sistemas, então se for utilizado apenas dois dígitos para o ano só serão reconhecidos anos com base nos dois primeiros anos de quatro dígitos da máquina (20YY).

Horas minutos segundos, reconhecemos por "**:**", se utiloza da siglas **HH24:MI:SS**, raro o uso de milissegundos, tão raro que não tenho um exemplo que a utilize, e por *MM* ser utilizado para identificar o mês, deve ser utilizado *MI* para representar os minutos.

Ao se juntar as duas formatações (data e hora) as separamos por um *espaço*, então o dia 17 de julho de 2018 da meia noite até 17 de julho de 2018 às 23:59:59 (que é o valor que você utilizou no seu exemplo) e representado dessa forma:

```
AND t.runstarttimestamp between
    to_date('17/07/2018 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and to_date('17/07/2018 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

A quebra de linha foi apenas para facilitar a leitura.

Espero que a resposta tenha sito útil, e a explicação não complexa.